# Add my own index.html to web browser in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#

I've written a simple index.html file my self. I would like to add it to my c# windows form application on a web browser.

I'm unclear on how to do that.

Any advice or example code I may look at will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Too broad. Please state a specific problem with a specific attempt to solve it using a specific code that is getting a specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the methods and such in the Object Browser window for the WebBrowser control. In particular, methods such as `Navigate` may be of interest to you.